# SQL to Linq C# EntityFrameWork Query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I can't write this query on EntityFrameWork. İt's so simple but I don't know yet EF.* I need 4 table left join on EF.

```
select ProductId,Name,ValueName,Value from ProductTechnicalInfo p 
left join ProductTechnicalInfoParameter pp on pp.ProductTechnicalInfoId = p.Id 
left join ProductTechnicalInfoValue v on v.ProductTechicalInfoId = p.Id
left join ProductTechnicalInfoValueParameter vp on vp.TechnicalValuesId=v.Id
where ProductId = 22
```

**My EF code :**

```
var infos = infoProductsRep.Join(transaction.ProductTechnicalInfoParameter, p => p.Id, pp => pp.ProductTechnicalInfoId, (ProductTechnicalInfo, ProductTechnicalInfoParameter) => new
{
    ProductTechnicalInfo,
    ProductTechnicalInfoParameter
}).Join(transaction.ProductTechnicalInfoValue, p => p.ProductTechnicalInfo.Id, v => v.Id, (Info, Value) => new
{
    Info,
    Value
}).Join(transaction.ProductTechnicalInfoValueParameter, p => p.Value.Id, vp => vp.TechnicalValuesId, (Info, Result) => new
{
    Info,
    Result
}).Where(x => x.Info.Info.ProductTechnicalInfo.ProductId == product.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: You're better off leaving this in SQL.  Use a Raw EF Query to execute it.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: Just FYI if you relations in the db and have set up you entities correctly you should rarely need joins.

Comment: @aaliakinci the real answer is `you don't need joins if you configure relations`

Comment: Are you using EF 6 or EF Core?  You tagged that you're using asp.net-core so I assuming you're using EF Core.  The query engine in EF Core was rewritten so you'll also need to provide the EF version #.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be some issues with property names, but your query is easily convertible to LINQ:

```cs
var query = 
    from p in infoProductsRep
    join pp in transaction.ProductTechnicalInfoParameter on p.Id equals pp.ProductTechnicalInfoId into gpp
    from pp in gpp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join v in transaction.ProductTechnicalInfoValue on p.Id equals v.ProductTechicalInfoId into gv
    from v in gv.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join vp in transaction.ProductTechnicalInfoValueParameter on p.Id equals vp.TechnicalValuesId into gvp
    from vp in gvp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where p.ProductId == 22
    select new 
    {
        p.ProductId,
        pp.Name,
        v.ValueName,
        vp.Value
    };

var result = query.ToList();
```